# How to save a workbook using InputBox in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to open and save a workbook based on what the use decides to name the file. I am able to open and save the workbook but I cannot figure out how to give the user the option to change the name of the save file. Here is my code:

```
Sub Sheets()

Dim wb1 As Workbook

wb1save = Application.InputBox("What would you like to save this file as?")

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Add

    wb1.SaveAs ("e:\excel\"Filename:=wb1save")

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a reason to use `Excel.Application.InputBox` over plain old `VBA.Interaction.InputBox` here. The function returns a null string pointer (kind of undocumented behavior though) if the user cancels the prompt, so you should handle that.

```
Dim result As String
result = InputBox(prompt, default)
If StrPtr(result) = 0 Then Exit Sub
wb1.SaveAs result
```

But don't use an `InputBox` for this (whether `Excel.Application.InputBox` or `VBA.Interaction.InputBox` - neither is meant for this kind of user input). Use `Application.GetSaveAsFileName` instead, and get an actual "SaveAs" dialog propmt the user for a filename, and let them browse folders and not make typos.

The function returns a `Boolean` value (`False`) if the user cancels the prompt, so you should handle that.

```
Dim result As Variant
result = Application.GetSaveAsFileName
If VarType(result) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub
wb1.SaveAs result
```

With that you're pretty much guaranteed to have a valid file/path. With `InputBox`, not so much.

The dialog will open on whatever the `CurDir` is, so you can use `ChDrive` and `ChDir` to control the default directory.

Comment: Agreed, no reason to use InputBox (and plenty of reasons not to). Favor `GetSaveAsFileName` or `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Had to play around a little bit but works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
Sub Sheets()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
wb1save = Application.InputBox("What would you like to save this file as?")
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
wb1.SaveAs ("e:\excel\" & wb1save)
End Sub
```

Comment: The issue is that you need the & symbol between the file path and the file name.  You also have to delete the Filename:= part and remove the last " in your code.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs, no it just saved a new workbook.  I didn't even notice that part of the code when I saw the obvious error I originally commented on.  Thanks for the catch, and I have updated my answer to save the current workbook

Comment: @GCC, If you use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` at the beginning of your code and `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` at the end of your code, you will not have the annoying pop up. And it will stop you from getting a `Run-time error '1004:` if you select `No` in the pop up. The file will be saved with the `.xlsx` extension